# What is the best way to draw something on an image in HTML?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I have a png which is a market plan. The idea is to make each spot on the plan clickable. I am plannig to achieve this using the `area` tag. I also want to show the user that non-available spots are red or marked with a cross or something. So I want to draw something on the image which indicates this. Now I am wondering what the best way is to achieve this. Does someone has a good idea for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you will have the coordinates of all spaces in your market-place.

Here's how to use those coordinates plus canvas to mark the un-available spaces in red:

- Size an offscreen canvas to the floorplan image's size
- Draw the floorplan on the canvas
- Use the unavailable coordinates to fill the canvas with semi-transparent red (or other color)
- Set the onscreen img element's .src to the canvas: img.src=canvas.toDataURL();

Code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Wj9Sx/

[image][image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // get reference to show(the checkbox) and img(the img)
    $show=$("#show");
    $show.hide();
    $show.change(function(){draw($show[0].checked);});
    $img=$("#plan");

    // create an offscreen canvas
    // used to put 
    var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // set coordinates for unavailable spaces
    var nonAvailable=[]
    nonAvailable.push([
        {x:100,y:27},
        {x:177,y:27},
        {x:138,y:91},
    ]);
    nonAvailable.push([
        {x:215,y:46},
        {x:260,y:92},
        {x:213,y:137},
        {x:168,y:92},
    ]);

    // load the floorplan img
    var img=new Image();
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/geo.png";

    // resize the canvas to the img size
    // display the img
    function start(){
        canvas.width=img.width;
        canvas.height=img.height;
        $show.show();
        var imgElement=document.getElementById("plan");
        imgElement.src=img.src;
    }

    // display the floorplan
    // optionally fill the unavailable spaces with transparent fill
    function draw(showUnavailable){

        // draw the floorplan
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

        // return if we're not showing unavailables
        if(showUnavailable){

            // set fill to 15% red
            ctx.save();
            ctx.fillStyle="red";
            ctx.globalAlpha=.15;

            // fill any non-available places
            // with semi-transparent red
            for(var i=0;i<nonAvailable.length;i++){
                var pts=nonAvailable[i];
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(pts[0].x,pts[0].y);
                for(var j=1;j<pts.length;j++){
                    ctx.lineTo(pts[j].x,pts[j].y);
                }
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
            }

            // restore the context state
            ctx.restore();
        }

        // draw the modified image back to the img element
        var imgElement=document.getElementById("plan");
        imgElement.src=canvas.toDataURL();

    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show">Indicate non-available spaces.<br>
    <img id="plan" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something called [a map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map) and position absolute on top of your image.

Or, you could use something called a [canvas tag in html5](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html) which needs javascript, although it is harder to use it is much more useful and stable

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't see how I can draw an image over an image?

Comment: canvas would definatley work while doing this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp it is something quite new and looking now more at your post this looks much more suited

Comment: Hi user3329290 - I hope you don't mind that I edited your post to include a link about the canvas tag. I also swapped out the w3schools link for a Wikipedia one. Please see http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Hi Chris thats great no worries.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should do this by creating those spots with other images and place them over that png. This way you can add hover effects etc to those spots..

like:

CSS:

```
#png1 {
  position: absolute; 
  z-index:1;
}

#spot1 {
  display: block; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index:2; 
  left: 10px; 
  top: 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position: relative">
  <img src="some.png" id="png1" />
  <a href="spot1" id="spot1"><img src="spot-red.png" /></a>
</div>
```